# How to create an instance of PDO without MySQL connection?

Tags: php, pdo

I have a CLI script that I use to build SQL. Part of the script requires escaping values, which usually would be done using [PDO::quote](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php). However, `PDO::quote` requires an instance of PDO.

Is there a way to have PDO instance without establishing a connection to the database?

Comment: You should think about implementing prepared statements rather than relying on escape functions.  Safer and more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. PDO's constructor requires parameters to connect to the database, and you won't get a PDO object if the connection fails.

Even if you could, `PDO::quote` depends on the driver to quote the value, so it needs the connection to work properly.

A better solution is to use prepared statements. If you can't or won't use that, you'll have to write a function to escape the values yourself.